# Why is Debian not showing the GPG signatures on keys that Arch Linux is?

Tags: key-management, gnupg

I downloaded a Qubes OS ISO and I'm trying to verify its legitimacy using [this guide](https://www.qubes-os.org/security/verifying-signatures/). GPG was behaving weirdly, so I created a separate user with a separate keyring to reproduce the issue.

When I try to verify the key on my Debian system, the signature on the release signing key is not there:

```
$ gpg --fetch-keys https://keys.qubes-os.org/keys/qubes-master-signing-key.asc
gpg: directory '/home/test/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/home/test/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: requesting key from 'https://keys.qubes-os.org/keys/qubes-master-signing-key.asc'
gpg: /home/test/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key DDFA1A3E36879494: public key "Qubes Master Signing Key" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
$ gpg --fetch-keys https://keys.qubes-os.org/keys/qubes-release-4-signing-key.asc
gpg: requesting key from 'https://keys.qubes-os.org/keys/qubes-release-4-signing-key.asc'
gpg: key 1848792F9E2795E9: public key "Qubes OS Release 4 Signing Key" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
$ gpg --list-sigs "Qubes OS"
pub   rsa4096 2017-03-06 [SC]
      5817A43B283DE5A9181A522E1848792F9E2795E9
uid           [ unknown] Qubes OS Release 4 Signing Key
sig 3        1848792F9E2795E9 2017-03-06  Qubes OS Release 4 Signing Key
$
```

I expected another line with a signature from the master key, such as

```
sig          DDFA1A3E36879494 2017-03-08  Qubes Master Signing Key
```

Surprised, I decided to check on another system. This one is running Arch Linux. I trust it less than the Debian system. Perplexingly, the signature *does* show up — the output is just as above, but with the added signature line.

The GPG version is `2.2.17` on both machines.

*What could be causing this discrepancy?*

Answer (score 3):

The root cause here is that

> the GnuPG developers broke gpg completely in a panic reaction
>
> -- [@knoblauchkeks on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Knoblauchkeks/status/1185730044406255616)

As explained in the [release notes for GnuPG 2.2.17](https://lwn.net/Articles/793288/),

> Ignore all key-signatures received from keyservers.  This
>       change is required to mitigate a DoS due to keys flooded with
>       faked key-signatures.  The old behaviour can be achieved by adding
>
> ```
> keyserver-options no-self-sigs-only,no-import-clean
> ```
>
> to your gpg.conf.  [#4607]

Adding this line to my (previously non-existent) `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and re-fetching the release key fixed the issue.

This does not happen on Arch Linux because [the maintainers decided to revert the commit that introduced this behavior](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/63147), which can be seen in [the build scripts for the package](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk/self-sigs-only.patch?h=packages/gnupg&id=ce66f685cf14e94c9f1aa6fb15abd017a830b64a):

```
prepare() {
    # ...
    patch -R -p1 -i ../self-sigs-only.patch
}
```

I [reported this issue](https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-issues/issues/5404) to Qubes, suggesting the documentation be modified to account for this in some way.